# N1ql query resetting document expiry time in couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have saved a document with expiry time of 20 seconds as shown below in my java code.

@Document(expiryExpression = "20",expiryUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)

public class Myclass {

it is deleting the document after 20 second which is fine.

But if i execute a N1ql within 20 seconds, the document is not getting deleted.
Execution time of N1ql is just 1 second.

Update Delivery d SET VehicleTrip.tripStatus = 'ENDED' where  meta(d).id = 'DD_1111_145469_2017-07-11'

my query is working fine, but the problem is document is not deleted once it complete 20 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Expiration time means that the document will be not available in memory storage in 20 seconds, it does not guarantee the same time for all persistent indexes, they might lag a bit.

Answer (score 0):

N1QL DMLs will not preserve expiration set by the SDK. If you modified document through N1QL you need to set the expiry again.